# tagging 'plain-language' vs technical definition in a SKOS vocabulary

Tags: standards, semantic-web, iso, skos

I am trying to implement a technical glossary in SKOS (which uses [BCP47](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt)) that has both a 'technical' scientific definition as well as a more accessible 'plain-language' definition.  I have not been able to  find an appropriate solution

Is there a best-practice for this ?

Comment: Could you please include an example of what the definitions would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific level of technicality expressible through SKOS, but you may look into other vocabularies to find a property that would suit your needs, for example on [Linked Open Vocabularies](https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov).

As for using such a property, I think the easiest would be to use `rdf:CompoundLiteral` to describe the literal itself:

```
<resource>
  skos:prefLabel [
    a rdf:CompoundLiteral ;
    rdf:value "layman term" ;
    rdf:language "en" ;
    :isTechnical false
  ] ;
  skos:altLabel [
    a rdf:CompoundLiteral ;
    rdf:value "technical term" ;
    rdf:language "en" ;
    :isTechnical true
  ] ;
```

Just remember that SKOS has an integrity condition such that only one `skos:prefLabel` may be present on a resource for a given language tag.

If you absolutely must use BCP47 (for language ranges, more restrictive formats etc.), I have tried to find a way to express what you want using existing standards and extensions, but I wasn't successful. In that case, the only remaining possibility is to use a private-use subtag, like `"term"@en-x-tech`.